# Scala Play framework beginner - 'Action Not Found'

Tags: scala, playframework

I've defined this entry in routes file :

```
GET     /proj/:value.id     controllers.MyController.Accessor(ident:Long)
```

To access this URL should I be able to use ? :

```
http://localhost:9000/proj/value.id=3
```

When I try this URL I receive

```
Action Not Found
For request 'GET /proj/value.id=3'
```

I think the format of my erequest is incorrect ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If ID is a path param, it should be:

```
GET     /proj/:id     controllers.MyController.Accessor(id: Long)
```

accessed as:

> http://localhost:9000/proj/3

If it's a query param, it should be:

```
GET     /proj     controllers.MyController.Accessor(id: Option[Long])
```

accessed as:

> http://localhost:9000/proj?id=3